# Uploading image in react form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to upload image from input type="file". I used example from mozilla docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL
But it's not working. That what I am getting:
[image]
[image]

This is the code:

HTML:

```
<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"/>
<img src="" height="200" alt="Image preview..."/>
```

JavaScript:

```
function previewFile() {
  var preview = document.querySelector('img');
  var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function () {
    preview.src = reader.result;
  }

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  } else {
    preview.src = "";
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this Reactjs ?

Comment: [This demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/4kcfw?file=/src/App.js) will probably give you an idea of what you did wrong.

Comment: Its javascript but I am gonna use it for react

Comment: If you want make it on react it's much easier.

Comment: @Yousaf its a great solution! How can I mark your answer as accepted?

Comment: @Oleg i just posted a comment, not an answer. You can accept the answer below if that helped you in any way.

Answer (score 1):

In Reactjs you can do it like this:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = React.useState("");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      setImageUrl(reader.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="file"
        name="image"
        onChange={handleChange}
        accept=".jpg,.png,.jpeg"
      />
      {imageUrl && <img src={imageUrl} alt="preview" />}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```